# How to filter JSON array based on children keys and merge into new array Angular 8

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular8

I am getting the below response, I want to ReGroup all the data and its children based on buSubRegion which is present inside children now. And also needs to add buSubRegion outside children.

**For EX -** In the below Response, `1UL Africa` belongs to the `Africa` object and is also present inside the `Europe` object, so I need to merge children of all objects which belong to 1UL Africa into one array of objects.

I want if buSubRegion has the same value and it is present inside many objects then find all those objects and merge them into one.

Also, Agbara - Savoury doesn't have a BU sub-region So I don't want to include this object.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

```
    const data = [
        {
          "name": "Africa",  
          "id":1,    
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Agbara - Laundry",
              "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa", 
              "children": [
                {
                  'lineId':"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                }
            ]        
             
            },
            {
              "name": "Agbara - Savoury",         
              "children": [
                {
                  "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                }
            ] 
            }
          ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Europe",  
            "id":2,    
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Europe1",
                "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa",
                "children": [
                    {
                      "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                    }
                ]            
              },
              {
                "name": "Europe2",
                "buSubRegion": "Test Europe",
                "children": [
                    {
                      "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                    }
                ] 
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Latem", 
            "id":3,     
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "test1",
                "buSubRegion": "latem1",
                "children": [
                    {
                      "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                    }
                ]           
              }
            ]
          }
      ];
```

**Below is my Expected Output**

```
    [
        {      
          "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa", 
          "name": "Africa",
          "id":1,     
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Agbara - Laundry",
              "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa",
              "children": [
                  {
                    "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                  }
              ] 
            },       
            {
                "name": "Europe1",
                "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa",
                "children": [
                    {
                      "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                    }
                ]            
            }      
          ]
        },
        {        
            "buSubRegion": "Test Europe",
            "name": "Europe", 
            "id":2,  
            "children": [         
              {
                "name": "Europe2",
                "buSubRegion": "Test Europe",
                "children": [
                    {
                      "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                    }
                ] 
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Latem", 
            "buSubRegion": "latem1",
            "id":3,     
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "test1",
                "buSubRegion": "latem1",
                "children": [
                    {
                      "lineId":"R_D005_TPKDST02"
                    }
                ]            
              }
            ]
          }
      ];
```

I tried the below code which was working perfectly and also giving output as per my expectation, But don't know why it was throwing an error in Angular Typescript and not returning any output. I am getting errors in the below line for ??= and semicolon ; Also I guess foreach is not supported in typescript.

**Can anyone help to make my code work**

```
  const result = data.reduce((a,{children, ...rest})=>{
      children.forEach(({buSubRegion,...others})=>{
          if(buSubRegion){
              a[buSubRegion] ??= {buSubRegion, ...rest, children:[]};
              a[buSubRegion].children.push({buSubRegion, ...others})
          }
      });
      return a;
  },{});
  console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: What's the error that you receive when you try this?

Comment: for id 2, you have 2 records in children array but in expected output you mentioned only 1 record in children

Comment: @Exception, Yes correct bcz from id 2 children i am moving one record in id 1 children, because its "buSubRegion": "1UL Africa", is matching with first array. I want to merge all children whose buSubRegion should be same. and my buSubRegion is dynamic, Everytime it check buSubRegion and if it is same then merge into similar children.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I defined the type of result as a `Record<K,V>`

```
    const result: Record<string, any> = {};

    this.data.reduce((acc, { children, ...rest }) => {
      children.forEach(({ buSubRegion, ...others }) => {
        if (buSubRegion) {
          acc[buSubRegion] ??= { buSubRegion, ...rest, children: [] };
          acc[buSubRegion].children.push({ buSubRegion, ...others });
        }
      });
      return acc;
    }, result);

    console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: `??=` is logical nullish assignment operator which only assigns if LHS is nullish. [check here for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment).

Refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals) to learn about spread operator.

Comment: But why it is not returning result always coming empty..can u make working demo with some mock data